# How to show dialogue box of rate app after X times?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

i made app with swift in Xcode and i have implemented Rate App Modal in my app but the problem is this its shown when users install the app and open for very first time but i want to show it after 2 or 3 days , so users can view my app and if he likes then he can rate my app. this is my code

```
 let reviewService = ReviewService.shared

       override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
             super.viewDidAppear(animated)
             let deadline = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(120)
             DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadline) { [weak self] in
                 self?.reviewService.requestReview()
             }
         }
```

and this is my ReviewService.swift file

```
 private init() {}
static let shared = ReviewService()

private let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
private let app = UIApplication.shared

private var lastRequest: Date? {
    get {
        return defaults.value(forKey: "ReviewService.lastRequest") as? Date
    }
    set {
        defaults.set(newValue, forKey: "ReviewService.lastRequest")
    }
}

private var oneWeekAgo: Date {
    return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: Date())!
}

private var shouldRequestReview: Bool {
    if lastRequest == nil {
        return true
    } else if let lastRequest = self.lastRequest, lastRequest < oneWeekAgo {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

func requestReview(isWrittenReview: Bool = false) {
  guard shouldRequestReview else { return }
    if isWrittenReview {
        let appStoreUrl = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/app/idxxxxxxx?action=write-review")!
        app.open(appStoreUrl)
    } else {
        if #available(iOS 10.3, *) {
            SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }
    lastRequest = Date()
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by after X times? Do you want to show it just one time, or every 2-3 days?

Comment: @NicolasElPapu X times mean when users open the app For X times , like when they open the app for 3 time then rate app pop should show up

Answer (score 0):

When the code finds that no previous request was saved don’t show the request. Instead save that the last request happened 4 or 5 days ago. Then in a few days the first review request will be shown.

One way to do this would be in the shouldRequestReview getter. If lastRequset is nil make a new post dated request time and save that, then return false.